# Reading string from a byte[]

Tags: c++

I have a byte array such as `0x21, 0x0D, 0x01, 0x03, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33` which containts the ascii string `"123"` with a length of 3. `(string starts at 0x03, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33)`
I'm learning, So would somebody be able to show me how to get the output `"123"` from it and put it inside a `char*`? Many thanks

```
                BYTE Data[] = { 0x0D, 0x01, 0x03, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33 };
                int Length = Data[2];

                //Extract string "123" from Data and store as char* ?
```

Comment: C++ doesn't have `byte[]`s.  Please show us your code.

Comment: where do you keep the bytes? cast that to char*, add a 0 at the end.

Comment: sorry, updated my question

Comment: what is `BYTE`? Looks very much like a macro. Please show the definition of it.

Comment: Both of the answers given rely on the execution character set being ASCII compatible and so are not completely portable (but practically, they'll be fine). If you want it to be portable, you'll need a lookup table that maps from the input bytes to the execution character set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have char sized data in BYTE type:

```
#include <iostream>
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
BYTE Data[] = { 0x0D, 0x01, 0x03, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33 };

int main() {
  std::string str(reinterpret_cast<char*>(Data) + 3, 3); 
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
  const char * c = str.c_str();
  std::cout << c << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This assumes, of course, that the ASCII data starts at position 3.  A valid assumption?  I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example:

```
#include <windows.h> // typedef for BYTE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> // isnum(), isalpha(), isprint(), etc

BYTE bytes[] = {
  0x21, 0x0D, 0x01, 0x03, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33
};

#define NELMS(A) (sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]))

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buff[80];
    for (int i=0, j=0; i < NELMS(bytes); i++) {
      if (isprint(bytes[i])) {
        buff[j++] = bytes[i];  
      }
    }
    buff[j] = '\0';
    printf ("buff=%s\n", buff);
    return 0;
}
```

EXAMPLE OUTPUT:

> buff=!123

You'll notice that "0x21" is a printable character ("!").  Instead of "isprint()" (is a printable ASCII character), you can use "isalpha()", or "isalnum()" instead.

'Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply, can the buff have the size of the bytes?

Comment: Yes, the NELMS (compile-time) macro I gave you can be use to set the buffer size, e.g. `char buff[NELMS(bytes)+1];`